# iPhone:Display UIPopoverController in MapView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, mkmapview, uipopovercontroller

I am working map app and I am display mapview in UIView that in which I display all locations in mapview. 
Now I want to display `UITableview` inside `UIPopoverController` when I selected a mappin.

Is it possible in iPhone??

Does any have an idea to how to develop this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, i think you can use the Delegate methods available for the AnnotationView

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
– mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:
```

In there you can check wich one is tapped and than open your UIPopOverController

Does this help you?